# Передать переменную в PHP

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте имеется такой скрипт, как передать значения отсюда

200

```js
$cena =  ПЕРЕДАТЬ НАДО СЮДА     ; // главная цена  
// курс валют 
$UAH = 0.4600; // для ГРН 
$USD = 0.0166; // для доллара
$RUB = 1.0000; // для RUB
$KZT = 5.5000; // для KZT



switch ($currency) 
{ 
case "USD": 
$sumaUSD = $cena * $USD; // формула 
echo "$sumaUSD $currency"; //результат 
break; 

case "UAH": 
$sumaUAH = $cena * $UAH; // формула 
echo "$sumaUAH $currency"; //результат 
break; 

case "RUB": 
$sumaRUB = $cena * $RUB; // формула 
echo "$sumaRUB $currency"; //результат 
break; 

case "KZT": 
$sumaKZT = $cena * $KZT; // формула 
echo "$sumaKZT $currency "; //результат 
break;

default: 
echo "$currency $cena RUB"; //вывод главной цены 
break; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Передать надо отсюда <p>200<p/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно отправить ajax запрос. 
Jquery

```
var perem = $(".class");

$.ajax({
     url: "ваш url",
     type: "GET",
     data: perem
});
```

Таким образом, на сервере в `$_POST` Будет эта переменная.
Можно также, попробовать передать в GET, но лучше все-таки Ajax.

Comment: получиться мне в $cena =$_POST['perem']

Comment: а в html $.ajax({
     url: "ваш url",
     type: "GET",
     data: 50
});

Сори за глупые вопросы просто почти нифига не понимаю в этом

Comment: Задмпите `$_POST`, и увидите как оно пришло. А в html, да так, только надо подключить Jquery.

Comment: Сделал вот так вот
`<div class="cehaa"><p>350</p></div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
 var perem = $(".cehaa");

$.ajax({
     url: "{full-link}",
     type: "GET",
     data: perem
});
 </script>`

В обработчик так $cena = `$_GET['cehaa']; // главная цена`
К сожалению я что то не так сделал наверное

Comment: Задампите GET вот так, и посмотрите `print_r($_GET);`. И да, в perem вы должны поместить так $(".cehaa").html();